# How can you use VIP Scanner to scan and test plugins

Tags: wordpress

VIP Scanner documentation talks about its ability to scan and test plugins but I cannot find anywhere that talks about how this is achieved. Can anyone provide any clarity on the ability to scan plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by following these steps

1. Clone the vip-quickstart project
2. In vip-quickstart dir start VM by running `vagrant up`
3. navigate to plugin dir i.e /srv/www/wp-content/plugins/{PLUGIN NAME}
4. run command `wp vip-scanner scan`

This scan provided all the errors that needed fixing for the WordPress VIP platform

Answer (score 1):

The best place I found was the Github respository for the plugin here:

[VIP Scanner Github Repository](https://github.com/Automattic/vip-scanner)

There is a file there called HACKING.md that has a code walkthrough. Hopefully that helps.